# VBA change cell value to run another macro

Tags: vba, excel

I hope you can help.

I have a lengthy piece of code, **CODE 2** what this does is it allows a user to open a dialog box, select a sheet, once a sheet is selected it formats the sheet, filters the 7th column then adds new sheets with copied information from 7th column, names the sheets, formats again, adds and deletes columns, subtracts dates and returns numbers, and I essentially end up with what you see in **Pic 1** (more happens but that is the gist of it) I am happy with **CODE 2**

I also have **CODE 1** now with this if a user selects a value in A2 that is not **"Enter Your Country Here"** then  all the **"Enter Your Country Here"** in the workbook get replaced with the new value in A2.

**CODE 1** also works fine

The problem is i cant seem to join **CODE 1** into **CODE 2**. **CODE 1** works perfectly by itself but I cant seem to call it or get it to fire where ever I place or call it in **CODE 2**

Can **CODE 1** be worked into **CODE 2** so that when a user selects a country it finds and replaces **"Enter Your Country Here"** with the selected value in A2

Like a said both codes work fine separately I just need to bring 1 into 2 some how

As always any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Pic 1 
[image]

CODE 1

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("A2")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
        ' changed.
        ' Place your code here.
        Call Find_Replace

    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Find_Replace()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fnd As Variant
Dim rplc As Variant

fnd = "Enter Your Country Here"
rplc = Worksheets("SearchCasesResults").Range("A2").Value

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Next sht

End Sub
```

CODE 2

```
Sub Open_Workbook_Dialog()

Dim my_FileName As Variant

    MsgBox "Pick your Disputes file" '<--| txt box for prompt to pick a file

        my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*") '<--| Opens the file window to allow selection

    If my_FileName <> False Then
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=my_FileName


Call Sort_Disputes   '<--|Calls Sort Disputes and begins to format

End If


End Sub

Public Sub Sort_Disputes()

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Rows("1:5").Delete '<--|Deletes the first 5 rows
Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert '<--|Inserts a new A column
Range("A1").Value = "Market" '<--|Market text enters cell A1
Cells(1, 2).Copy
Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats) '<--|Keeps the formatting of other columns and forces to new column A
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Columns.AutoFit '<--|Auto fits the columns
Range("C:C,J:J,M:AF").EntireColumn.Delete '<--|Deletes Columns
Rows("2:2500").RowHeight = 25 '<--|Adjusts Row Height

Call populateA '<--|Calls PopulateA and this takes a look a Column A and where blank enters text

End With


Call Filter '<--|Calls Filter which looks down the 7th Column and seperates out the sheets to new tabs based on the value in Column 7

Call Activate_Sheet '<--|Deletes a column then subtracts todays date from the date in C and represents as a number in D

Call Activate_Sheet_2 '<--|As long as C is not blank it will subtract the Date in C from the Date in D and return a numerical result

Call Add_Sheet

End Sub

Public Sub Filter()
    Dim rCountry As Range, helpCol As Range

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1) '<--| refer to data worksheet
        With .UsedRange
            Set helpCol = .Resize(1, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count) '<--| get a "helper" column just at the right of used range, it'll be used to store unique country names in
        End With

        With .Range("A1:Q" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) '<--| refer to its columns "A:Q" from row 1 to last non empty row of column "A"
            .Columns(7).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=helpCol, Unique:=True '<-- call AdvancedFilter on 7th column of the referenced range and store its unique values in "helper" column
            Set helpCol = Range(helpCol.Offset(1), helpCol.End(xlDown)) '<--| set range with unique names in (skip header row)
            For Each rCountry In helpCol '<--| iterate over unique country names range (skip header row)
                .AutoFilter 7, rCountry.Value2 '<--| filter data on country field (7th column) with current unique country name
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell other than header ones has been filtered...
                    Worksheets.Add Worksheets(Worksheets.Count) '<--... add new sheet
                    ActiveSheet.Name = rCountry.Value2  '<--... rename it
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 'copy data for country under header
                End If
            Next
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove autofilter and show all rows back
    End With
    helpCol.Offset(-1).End(xlDown).EntireColumn.Delete '<--| clear helper column (header included)


End Sub

Public Sub populateA()

Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    With WS
        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '<--| Looks for the last empty cell in Column B

        .Range("A2:A" & lRow).Formula = "=If(B2<>"""",""Enter Your Country Here"","""")" '<--| If there is no blank cell in B and A has a blank cell then A gets populated with "Enter your Country Here"
        .Range("A2:A" & lRow).Value = .Range("A2:A" & lRow).Value
        .Range("A2:A" & lRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 39 '<--|Changes the colour of A
    End With

End Sub

Public Sub Activate_Sheet()

Worksheets("In Progress").Activate '<--|Activates Inprogress Sheet
Columns.AutoFit '<--|Auto fits Columns
Range("N:N").EntireColumn.Delete '<--|Delete Columns
Range("D1").Value = "# days open" '<--|Enters Value
Rows("2:2500").RowHeight = 25 '<--|Adjusts Row Height

Dim LastRow  As Long, i As Long
With Worksheets("In Progress")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row '<--|Looks for the last non empty cell in C

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        .Range("D" & i).Value = DateDiff("d", .Range("C" & i).Value, Date) '<--|As long as C is not blank it will subtract todays date from C and populate in D
    Next i
End With

End Sub

Public Sub Activate_Sheet_2()

Worksheets("Complete").Activate '<--|Activates Complete Sheet
Columns.AutoFit '<--|Auto fits Columns
Range("N:N").EntireColumn.Delete '<--|Deletes Columns
Range("E1").EntireColumn.Insert '<--|Inserts Columns
Range("E1").Value = "Overall Ticket Aging" '<--|Enters Value
Rows("2:2500").RowHeight = 25 '<--|Adjusts Row Height

Dim LastRow  As Long, i As Long
With Worksheets("Complete")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        .Range("E" & i).Value = DateDiff("d", .Range("C" & i).Value, .Range("D" & i).Value) '<--|As long as C is not blank it will subtract the Date in C from the Date in D and return a numerical result
    Next i
End With
Columns(5).NumberFormat = "0" '<--|Formats the 5 column to number format
End Sub

Public Sub Add_Sheet()
''Dim WS As Worksheet
''Set WS = Sheets.Add
Sheets.Add.Name = "Countries"
Worksheets("Countries").Activate
Range("A1").Value = "Country"
Range("A2").Value = "UK"
Range("A3").Value = "Belgium"
Range("A4").Value = "Bulgaria"
Range("A5").Value = "Croatia"
Range("A6").Value = "Czech Republic"
Range("A7").Value = "Slovenia"
Range("A8").Value = "Spain"
Range("A9").Value = "Italy"
Range("A10").Value = "Germany"
Worksheets("SearchCasesResults").Activate

Call Auto_Filter
End Sub

Public Sub Auto_Filter()

'replace "J2" with the cell you want to insert the drop down list
With Range("A2").Validation
.Delete
'replace "=A2:A6" with the range the data is in.
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Countries!A2:A10"
.IgnoreBlank = True
.InCellDropdown = True
.InputTitle = ""
.ErrorTitle = ""
.InputMessage = ""
.ErrorMessage = ""
.ShowInput = True
.ShowError = True
End With

End Sub
```

To solve this I needed VBA code that would put Change Event VBA code into another worksheet. Calling the code I had was not working as I was calling a Change Event which didn't make sense. I needed code to put the change event into the sheet.

The code I used to put the change event into the the sheet in my example in the pic the sheet named "SearchCasesResults" is below I hope it helps someone.

CODE to put code into another sheet

```
Public Sub CreateEventProcedure()
        Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
        Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
        Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
        Dim LineNum As Long
        Const DQUOTE = """" ' one " character
        Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
        Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Sheet1")
        Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

        With CodeMod
            LineNum = .CreateEventProc("Change", "Worksheet")
            LineNum = LineNum + 1
            ''.InsertLines LineNum, "    MsgBox " & DQUOTE & "Hello World" & DQUOTE
            ''.InsertLines LineNum, "  Cells.Columns.AutoFit"
            ''.InsertLines LineNum, "  End Sub"
            .InsertLines LineNum, "  Worksheets(" & DQUOTE & "SearchCasesResults" & DQUOTE & ").Activate"
            .InsertLines LineNum, "  Next sht"
            .InsertLines LineNum, "  SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False"
            .InsertLines LineNum, "  LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _"
            .InsertLines LineNum, "  sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _"
            .InsertLines LineNum, "  For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets"
            .InsertLines LineNum, "  rplc = Worksheets(" & DQUOTE & "SearchCasesResults" & DQUOTE & ").Range(" & DQUOTE & "A2" & DQUOTE & ").Value"
            .InsertLines LineNum, "  fnd = " & DQUOTE & "Enter Your Country Here" & DQUOTE & ""
            .InsertLines LineNum, "  Dim rplc As Variant"
            .InsertLines LineNum, "  Dim fnd As Variant"
            .InsertLines LineNum, "  Dim sht As Worksheet"


        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Code2 runs on demand. Code1 runs in response to user's actions. They should stay separate unless I completely misunderstand what and why you are trying to do.

Comment: GSerg I think you misunderstand: I want Code 1 in Code 2 so that when  a user selects cell A2 Code 1 fires. the question is how do I get that to happen I need Code 2 to go ah yes here is Code 1 work. At the moment that is not happening. Can I embedded or call Code 1 in Code 2 somehow?

Comment: This is slightly off topic but in CODE 2 Sort_Disputes() your With block isn't doing anything without a period. Unless you have ".Rows("1:5").Delete" its just taking the active sheet not sheet 1.

Comment: Berticus Yes off topic but again yes just taking active sheet not sheet 1 admittedly I am an UGLY coder but if it works I run it. :-)

Comment: I'm still not sure I follow. If you don't know how to call code1 from code2 but do know when to call it, then, code1's event handler `Worksheet_Change` is a sub like any other, and you can call it like any other sub. You seem to like `Call`, so put `Call Worksheet_Change(some_range)` in code2 where you see fit. `some_range` must be some relevant range, e.g. `Range("A2")`. If you know that but don't know where in code1 to put that call, then I doubt I can help because only you know where it should happen.

Comment: Code1 is an event that fires when cell A2 is changes, Code2 is a macro that must be run.   So what is your expected workflow? What you're asking for by having Code1 IN Code2 means the workflow is "User Runs Macro "Open_Workbook_Dialog" -> Code2 runs -> Code1 runs" which doesn't make sense because the user hasn't edited the A2 (changed the country)  So please spell out what you expect to happen.  You can do "User changes the country in A2 to "Belgium" -> Run Code1 -> Run Code2" very easily, but doing it the other way around doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hi both: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I know my method is confusing. I need the change event code to be present in Sheet 1. I have found code that will put code into a sheet. I needed the change event to be on Sheet1 or  "SearchCasesResults" sheet in my pic. So I now have code that will add a change event macro to ""SearchCasesResults" sheet and once there if the cell changes then everything should work but I am now having issues with entering string like "Enter Your Country Here" with the new Macro. I have made an edit in the question to better explain.

Comment: Hi all. I have found the solution: What needed to be done was to put the change event into the "SearchCasesResults" sheet or sheet 1 once I found the VBA to do this then it was easy. I apologize for the confusion I am still on the VBA learning curve. Thank you again for the support.